# Replace property placeholders in spring profile-specific properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

I am writing a test for a spring boot application and I am facing a weird behaviour with the placeholder replacement in the profile-specific application properties file.

So, in my settings.xml I have my DB creds set up like

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <properties>
            <db.user>MyLogin</db.user>
            <db.password>MyPassword</db.password>
            <db.url>my_db_connection_url</db.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

So there is only one profile in settings.xml. In the application I have a profile-specific application properties file like that:

`application-myprofile.properties` :

```
spring.datasource.url=@db.url@
spring.datasource.username=@db.user@
spring.datasource.password=@db.password@
```

and while I am starting the spring boot application with a specific profile `myprofile` - it all works just fine, creds are being pulled from the settings.xml.

However, for the tests I have a slightly different setup.

I have a test class like that:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("mytestprofile")
public class MyTest {
    ....
}
```

and a corresponding test profile properties file inside `test/resources` like that

`application-mytestprofile.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=@db.url@
spring.datasource.username=@db.user@
spring.datasource.password=@db.password@
```

and in this case the placeholders are not being replaced by the values from `settings.xml`. However, if I replace the content of `application-mytestprofile.properties` with

```
spring.datasource.url=my_db_connection_url
spring.datasource.username=MyLogin
spring.datasource.password=MyPassword
```

it works just fine. Also, if I put the placeholders inside the `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=@db.url@
spring.datasource.username=@db.user@
spring.datasource.password=@db.password@
```

it also works.

The question is: why is that? How can I make a profile-specific application properties file work with `settings.xml` in tests?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the details about your project setup, but it looks like you have a test folder structure like this:

```
test 
    -> java 
            -> resources
```

while I think it should be

```
test 
    -> java
    -> resources
```

So, move your test resources folder one level up, and it should work.

Comment: nope, I have it as `test/resources` and `test/java`

Comment: Well, if you still need help here, you should consider to share a non-working example project.